# htmlspecialchars function is returning null

Tags: php

```
<?php

$email = mysqli_stmt_bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_stmt_bind_param("s", $_POST['password']);

$select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM faculty where facultyEmail = $email");

if(mysqli_num_rows($select)==0){
    $result = array("status"=>0, "msg"=>"Faculty Member Does Not Exist");
}else{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
        $checkPassword = $row['password'];
    }
    if($password==$checkPassword){
        #Use encrypted password instead.
        $result = array("status"=>1, "msg"=>"Faculty Member now logged in.");
    }else{
        $result = array("status"=>0, "msg"=>"Password entered is wrong.");
    }
}   
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array("index" => htmlspecialchars($result)));
?>
```

The htmlspecialchars() function is returning null. I'm trying to prevent it from XSS attack. How can it be solved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `htmspecialchars` requires a string.  You are passing an array.

Comment: That is not how binding works. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php Also hash your passwords, don't encrypt and don't store plain text.

Comment: You might getting this error `E_WARNING : type 2 -- htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given -- at line`

Comment: No I'm not getting any error. But it is returning null.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM faculty where facultyEmail = $email` would never work, you aren't checking for errors.